# Call Win32 DeviceWatcher API from Dynamic Link Library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, dll

I create a DLL project in VS 2022. How is it possible to add a call to the Win32 [`DeviceWatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.devicewatcher?view=winrt-22621) API?

I need to add this to use it:

```
using namespace Windows::Devices::Enumeration;
using namespace Windows::Foundation
```

But where must I add references to the Win32 API?

Comment: The `DeviceWatcher` type is part of the Windows Runtime, not the Win32 API. [Consume APIs with C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/consume-apis) explains the fundamentals (assuming that you're using [C++/WinRT](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DeviceWatcher Class` is Windows Runtime API. I suggest you should create a `Windows Runtime component DLL` or `class library universal windows`.

For more details I suggest you could refer to the Doc: [DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/dlls-c-cx?view=msvc-170)